# what is fill="url(#gradient-3)" in css

Tags: css, internet-explorer, gradient

I know `url(#grdient-3)` which only works in IE.

And I wanna know what's means about `#grdient-3`.

How to I convert it to `gradient-linear`, for example to use with `-moz-linear-gradient`?

I found out it, it's means use element with `grdient-3` in html

for example `fill=“url(#gradient-3)”`

```
<linearGradient id="gradient-3" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">>
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgba(149, 76, 233, 1)" stop-opacity="0.07"/>
    <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="rgba(149, 76, 233, 1)" stop-opacity="0.13"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgba(149, 76, 233, 1)" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
```

Comment: I think this only applies to SVGs, though. Maybe tag SVG as well?

Comment: This is not html :) Only look like.